# how to test the loading of UI, in case it is written in Typescript, using Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, query-optimization, profiler, ui-testing

My application uses, Angular 9, and in that, the typescript is used for UI, and it is converted on run time
And thee issue is that the page is taking time to load
So for that, I have checked the queries by optimizing them, still, the issue is same
So need to check UI loading time, so how can we test that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot test UI loading time using JMeter itself, as per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level**. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if you need to test the performance of page rendering it's better to consider specialized solutions like [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse).

If your test framework is built around JMeter and you need to add client-side performance testing to your test suite you can consider using [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mixing-selenium-into-your-load-scenario) which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework.